# using declaration inside a member function for an inherited member field

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-directives

Inside a function one can employ the using declaration to import a name in the current scope, like

```
namespace A {
   int y;
}

void f() { using A::y; }
```

A using declaration can be used in a class definition, to alter the accessibility of an inherited member, but also it is useful to explicitly bring a member inherited from a template class

```
template <bool activate>
struct A {
   int x;
};

template <bool activate>
struct B : public A<activate> {
   using A<activate>::x;
};
```

This is particularly useful, as it avoids the need to access to `x` via `this->x` or `A<activate>::x`. This can be used only inside the body of the definition, but not inside a member function.

```
template <bool activate>
struct A {
   int x;
};

template <bool activate>
struct B : public A<activate> {
   int f() const noexcept {
       // This gives: "error: using-declaration for member at non-class scope"
       // using A<activate>::x;
       return x;
   }
};
```

Is there a rationale for this restriction of the language, that is, for the fact that `using A<activate>::x` can only be placed inside the definition of the class?

Comment: fyi MSVC compiles this - live - https://godbolt.org/z/4d6Txb5M8

Comment: BTW, `using A<true>::x` does not work if activate is `false`

Comment: @RichardCritten only until you instantiate `f`.

Comment: @AspectOfTheNoob Ah, sorry, I intended of course ```using A<activate>::x```, I amended the question

Comment: @n.m. Thank you. Now it fails, Updated live - https://godbolt.org/z/a1f5GMaEo

Comment: Meanwhile, you can do `auto& x = A<activate>::x;`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sYseE69K7)

Comment: You can write `B::x` to refer to inherited members like this, which is more broadly applicable than `this->` and usually shorter than naming the base specialization.

Comment: Perhaps nobody wrote a convincing proposal to add this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Absent a direct statement on the subject in *Design & Evolution of C++*, it’s hard to reliably infer intent for something like this.  That said, until [recently](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), the standard described *using-declaration*s as **introducing** declarations as synonyms for the named declarations.  In that view, it would be more than a little strange to have a member declaration belong to a block scope.  Now they are considered to be **redirects** that are replaced by their referents during name lookup, which would be more consistent with this notional usage.